# How can I remove a view I added to navigationcontroller view?

Tags: ios, view, uinavigationcontroller

So I have a settings bar button item in my navigation controller which, when pressed from a home view controller, opens a settings vc transparent view over the home vc, so the home vc is still visible behind the settings vc. I want the nav bar to still show, so in the "HomeViewController.h"I have the following code :

```
-(IBAction)settingsButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    SettingsViewController *settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:settings.view];
}
```

When I want to remove the settings view, in "SettingsViewController" I tried doing :

```
-(IBAction)exitSettings:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

But when I do this and try to run the program, the program stops, and in the debug area, it just says

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address=0xb0000008)
(lldb)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this???

Comment: you want to remove navigation controller

Comment: You're trying to remove navigationController's view from the hierarchy, you probably want `[self.view removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: I don't want to remove the navigation controller, I want to remove the settings view and show the home view with the navigation controller again. And I tried calling removeFromSuperview from self.view, but the same thing happens, but with the address=0xf

Comment: Just a moment... where is `-(IBAction)exitSettings:(id)sender` located? In your home controller or the settings one?

Comment: that is located in the settings view controller

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here crash occurred because of this code:

```
[self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

You are trying to remove the `navigationController` view not the settings view.

When you add the `SettingsViewController` add a `tag` to it:

```
-(IBAction)settingsButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    SettingsViewController *settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc]init];
    settings.view.tag = 7;
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:settings.view];
}
```

And use this `tag` to remove the view from the navigationcontroller:

```
-(IBAction)exitSettings:(id)sender
{
    [[self.navigationController.view viewWithTag:7] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: I've actually seen that I should try to add a tag to the view, but I have the `-(IBAction)exitSettings:(id)sender` in the SettingsViewController.h and the `-(IBAction)settingsButtonPressed:(id)sender` in the HomeViewController.h, so I don't see how the tag would affect calling the exit button, I tried adding a tag to the SettingsViewController.xib file, but I get the same error

Comment: Can you please try my answer ? do the exact steps. No need to add tag to xib. It'll work

Comment: There will be no errors, if the `viewWithTag` not matches it will simply return nil. So There will be no such errors. Ok try one thing:
Please change the `exitSettings` method like:
`-(IBAction)exitSettings:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Error or Not: %@",[self.navigationController.view viewWithTag:7]);
}`

Comment: I don't get a message in the debug area, I am doing something wrong with the button I placed in the SettingsViewController.xib file? Because I'm guessing this means that there is an error before it runs the `-(IBAction)exitSettings:(id)sender`, but after I press the button connected to that function

Comment: @user1828659: I'm also thinking that crash is happening somewhere else. After fixing that issue, you can use the above code and it'll work :)

Comment: I appreciate the help a lot! Now all that's left is to find this error, thanks for your time! =D

Comment: @user1828659: I'll help you to fix it also, it can be easily fixed like: create a property like: `@property(nonatomic, strong) SettingsViewController *settings;` and use `self.settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc]init];` Remove the local object :) Check it

Comment: =O THAT WORKED!!!!! THANK YOUUUU!!! I feel bad for bothering you with this again since you have helped me so much already, but now that `-(IBAction)exitSettings:(id)sender { NSLog(@"Error or Not: %@",[self.navigationController.view viewWithTag:7]); }` is coming up as NULL, any idea why that is?

Comment: I got it! Since I'm calling the `-(IBAction)exitSettings:(id)sender` from the SettingsViewController.h, I tried doing just `[self.view viewWithTag:7]removeFromSuperView]` and it worked! Again, thank you very very much, I appreciate all the help you have given me!! =D

Comment: @user1828659: With Pleasure :) All the best

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.view.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[SettingsViewController class]])
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
-(IBAction)exitSettings:(id)sender
{
      [vc dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

vc is your ViewController Object.

try this one.

Comment: He doesn't present the controller modally in the first place. So this is not going to work...